# NSAnimation does not work with large NSViews

Tags: swift, macos, nsanimationcontext, nsanimation

The code below works fine when I change the NSTextfield coordinate in an NSView with a width of 1000; however, it does not work when the view width is more than ~10000. There is no animation and the text just jumps to the new coordinate.

```
if isAnimateDataLabel {
    lb.frame.origin.y = 0
    NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { context in
        context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
        context.duration = 0.5
        lb.animator().frame.origin.y = y + offset
    }
}
```

I am a bit baffled by the issue and cannot pinpoint the root cause and the fix. Please suggest if you can figure out the issue.

Comment: What are the values of `lb.frame.origin.y` before `isAnimateDataLabel` and `y + offset`? From where do you call `isAnimateDataLabel`?

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for your response. `isAnimateDataLabel` is a class property that is updated while initializing the class. The value of `lb.frame.origin.y` was 0 before and y was 100 and offset was 10. I have tried multiple times, same code works when the NSView width is not too large.

Comment: When is the code executed?

Comment: The code is triggered from the drawRect function of the view.

Comment: `drawRect` should draw, nothing else.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I will tweak the code and will call this function from outside the draw function. I believe once I have made the change to the `isAnimateDataLabel`property I might have to put `needDisplay = true`. Will try and report on the outcome. Thank you.